# Naming a file with the for loop variable

Tags: python, for-loop

I am writing an image processing function and I am using a for loop to test different parameters. I want to save the resultant image from each with the corresponding parameter but cannot successfully insert that variable into the file name. Code is below

```
for j in np.arange(.1,1,.1):
     noisy = img_as_float(grayscale)
     sigma_est = estimate_sigma(noisy, multichannel=False, 
                       average_sigmas=False)
     Bilateral = denoise_bilateral(noisy, sigma_color=j, sigma_spatial=15,
                                      multichannel=False)
     plt.imshow(Bilateral)
     print (j)
     parameter= print(type(j))
     io.imsave (parameter + "4311_denoise", Bilateral)
```

I get the error:
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'NoneType' and 'str'

Can anyone help me list the given j parameter as str in the filename?

Thanks!

Comment: ``print`` returns ``None``. Did you mean to use ``str`` instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I *think* you meant to do this:

```py
for j in np.arange(.1,1,.1):
     noisy = img_as_float(grayscale)
     sigma_est = estimate_sigma(noisy, multichannel=False, 
                       average_sigmas=False)
     Bilateral = denoise_bilateral(noisy, sigma_color=j, sigma_spatial=15,
                                      multichannel=False)
     plt.imshow(Bilateral)

     filename = f"{j}_4311_denoise"
     print(f"will save image to {filename}")
     io.imsave(filename, Bilateral)
```

This will create images under the filenames 0.1_4311_denoise, 0.2_4311_denoise and so forth.

Using a f-string instead of concatenating the variables with `+` is generally more robust and flexible.